# How to create a zip from an array of Blobs with a folder structure

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, zip, directory-structure

I get how to create a zip from an array of Blobs, but is it somehow possible to define a folder structure within the zip itself?

for example.. archive/img/file1.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, although it's not readily apparent.

First, it's important to understand that the [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob) objects in Google App Scripts are a little different than JavaScript's normal [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) objects. The most important difference is that they have a name, and many parts of the API use this name. (Including Utilities.zip())

Utilities.zip() treats the name on a blob as a pathname, so you can build entire hierarchies by just including slashes:

```
//Create a test blob
var blob = Utilities.newBlob("My Data");
blob.setName("foo/bar.txt");
//Should be a zip containing a folder named "foo", which contains a file named "bar.txt", which has the contents "My Data"
var zipBlob = Utilities.zip([blob], "test.zip");
```